# Changing Polygon clearnce in Altium

Tags: altium

I need to change the polygon clearance. Here are my setting rules.
[image]
[image]

But it seems that the lower rule for all clearances is superior to the second one and nothing has been changed. what is my mistake that the first rule is superior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the priorities of the rules, with that eponymous button down at the bottom of the screen. 1 is the highest.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.